# What do you call a text stating someone's expert opinion about an academic work?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I'm translating a template for a job application, and now I'm stuck on the following sentence:

> Any expert opinion regarding your doctoral thesis should be included with the application

Does the reference to "expert opinion" make any sense? Or should I phrase it differently? If so, how? I'm thinking about the kind of written statement/assessment you may get from the review board or some other expert in connection to your public defence.

Comment: It seems to me that you have already written what you mean: “documents accepted by the board in reviewing or assessing the dissertation.” I doubt there is any term of art that abbreviates this. Furthermore, “expert opinion” is a vague term.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Thanks for your input! What I'm after is not the assessment support though, but rather an "appraisal" of the thesis, written by the review board or some other expert. I agree "expert opinion" is a vague term, but that's ok in the context (it's vague in the original as well) – I'm more interested in whether it makes any sense at all, to use "expert opinion" about a piece of writing...

Comment: The term [**monograph**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monograph) is broadly similar to what you want, though it implies more research and detail than you are asking for.

Comment: “final appraisal (however titled) of your doctoral dissertation by its review board” seems to do the trick.

Comment: That is a mistranslation, for sure. The opinion would come from an academic or PhD who is an "**The opinion of an expert in the field**"

Comment: I can just see the French: Tout opinion etc. In English, we would never start this sentence with: Any.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Yes!! If that sounds right to a native speaker, that's exactly what I'm after! I just wasn't sure "appraisal" could be used in this context. Thank you!

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I didn't know that! So you can't express "if you have any"/"If there are any" in this way? "Any questions should be posed after the presentation"; "Any flammable goods should be packed separately"; "Any further complaints should be sent to the head of department" and so on – don't these work in English?

Comment: Can you please clarify: Is this for people with Phds getting a job? If that is so, I most definitely would use: opinion from an expert in the field. Of course, you can say "if you any etc." in English but here that style would not be good.

Comment: I would use the word [critique](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/critique) or “a critical essay or analysis; an instance of formal criticism”, but I’m not certain it’s appropriate for a thesis. It’s more often used for literature or art.

Comment: I would think what is being requested here is a brief appraisal by a _subject-matter expert_, that is, someone who is recognized in the field of study covered by your thesis.

Comment: @Lambie Yes! Exactly! That's exactly the context :) Thanks for your input! Very helpful! So, how would you express the 'if you have' sense in this context then? "Possible opinions on your doctoral thesis from an expert in the field should be included..."?

Comment: @RobJarvis Yes, exactly – that's exactly what I'm after! So, you're saying I can use "appraisal" for this?

Comment: I have given my answer *but*  the opinion of a subject-matter [RobJarvis]expert is good too. appraisal is not good. appraisal sounds like real estate to me.

Comment: @Lambie – right; that's what I thought too... about "appraisal", that is. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: In light of others' comments, I think maybe "evaluation" or "review" would be a better word choice than "appraisal".

Answer (score 1):

**An opinion from an expert in the field**

[Phd and letters of recommendation](https://studyabroad.careers360.com/articles/letter-of-recommendation-for-phd-students#:%7E:text=PhD%20application%20usually%20requires%20at,their%20resume%2C%20transcripts%20and%20SOP.)

Comment: Thank you – a letter of recommendation is something else entirely though, viz a letter explaining why a candidate is particularly suited for a specific job or position, right? What I'm after is simply a written statement expressing an expert opinion on a doctoral thesis.

Comment: This is not about a specific job or position. It is about why the candidate is suited for **admission to the PhD program**, which means to be suited to study and write papers in a particular field. It would be good to know the language and the country by the way. I happen to be a translator myself with 35 yrs. of experience across a number of subject areas.

Comment: Yes, exactly, so not quite what I was after. My bad though; I totally see that it's my fault for not being very clear... Language: Swedish to English; Country: Sweden.

Comment: @Helen Things are still not completely clear. According to normal academic usage in the U.S., if someone has a PhD, they will have written a dissertation rather than a doctoral thesis. Someone applying to enter a doctoral program will thus not have a doctoral dissertation to be evaluated. They may have a master’s thesis to be evaluated.

Comment: Moreover, this thread started with a question about “expert opinion,” a term that I have heard primarily in a legal context rather than an academic context. I like Lambie’s answer (and have upvoted it), but given the actual context, I would modify it to “academically recognized expert”

Comment: @JeffMorrow Oh – I thought "doctoral thesis" is the same thing as "doctoral dissertation"? Either way, what I mean is the long text someone writes, based on their own original research, to earn a PhD.

Comment: @Helen See https://dissertationteam.com/blog/thesis-vs-dissertation/